# Accessing index of a string within a comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, list-comprehension

```
>> names = ["Cola", "Salah"]  
>> names1 = [s for s in names for i,c in enumerate(s)]
Output: "Cola","Cola","Cola","Cola","Salah","Salah","Salah","Salah","Salah",
```

I am trying to use python comprehension so that instead of outputting Cola and Salah 5 times, the output would be:

```
output: "Coolllaaaa", "Saalllaaaahhhhh"
```

I am wondering how would we access the index of the string.
The code should be able to accept unicode.

Comment: Your code is already accessing the index - that's the `i` variable. You just need to use it now (see answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using [`enumerate`](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-enumerate-a-range-of-numbers-starting-with-1-in-python) to loop over each index and character in a string element:

```
>>> names = ["Cola", "Salah"]
>>> [''.join([c * i for i, c in enumerate(s, 1)]) for s in names]
['Coolllaaaa', 'Saalllaaaahhhhh']
```

This uses two `list` comprehensions, the first one to loop over each string in `names`, and the second one to loop over each character and index within the string, then multiply these values together and join them into a new string.

Comment: There's no reason to bother with `range`; `enumerate` can be passed an argument for the `start` index, it needn't start at `0`. So `[''.join([c * i for i, c in enumerate(s, 1)]) for s in names]` works just fine, and it's faster, simpler, less brittle (no computing lengths and tweaking `range` offsets) and more performant than `zip`+`range`.

Comment: Yep, I had updated my answer a while back when I figured that `enumerate` can be passed a start index. I'll remove the zip+range approach, since I suppose that's not really optimal here.